# Laravel 4: save a polymorphic relationship's record: undefined method newQuery()

Tags: polymorphism, laravel, polymorphic-associations, laravel-4

I have a polymorphic relationship in Laravel 4 and it's working like I want. I have another one, which doesn't work when I try to insert the related model, even though it is identical to the first one and I use it in the same way.

I have `Event` model and an `Article` model:

```
// Article Model
class Article extends Eloquent {
    public function events() {
        return $this->morphMany('Event', 'eventable');
    }
    ...

// Event Model
class Event extends Eloquent {
    public function eventable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$article = Article::find($article_id);
// insert
// neither of the following lines work
$article->events()->create(array("type" => "click"));
$article->events()->save(new Event(array("type" => "click")));
```

I get the same error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::newQuery() in
\app_path\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 383
```

What am I doing wrong? I have an identical situation with an Article and it's Photos, but there it works (it's also a polymorphic relation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Event is likely a reserved word in Laravel. Unless you namespace it, i'd suggest avoiding creating a class called Event, since it is like used in Laravel core. Something like activity could potentially serve as an alternative.

Comment: That's it. I never would have thought of that!

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had the same error message because of having a table named `events`. Changed the name and problem solved!

Comment: This SSOOOOO common in laravel 4 i think they need to rename the event class

Comment: Rename, no. Just use namespaces for your classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php