# Laravel-4 Polymorphic Relationship Only Assigning the Type (not the Id)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I am attempting to setup a polymorphic relationship with Laravel. I have read through the documentation and looked through related code but cannot seem to get all of it working. I am trying to attach `photos` to `rooms` where a room can have many photos. The `type` associated with the relationship works but the `id` is always `0`.

Why would part of it work, and can someone please point out what any issues in my relationship?

I believe the problem is related to how I am creating the data in the table:

```
$photo = new Photo;
$photo->URL = 'thePhotoURL.extension';
$photo->save();

$room = new Room;
$room->name = 'Some Room Name';
// seems weird to me that I "save" the photo twice
// or am I just saving the relationship here?
// have tried the other relationship options too (associate, attach, synch)
$room->photos()->save($photo);
// have also tried:
// $room->photos()->save(new Photo(array('URL' => 'urlTest.com')));
// get error "URL"

$room->save();
```

Creating Photos table:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('photos', function($t) {

        $t->increments('id');

        // ... ...
        // the Id is always 0 but the type is correct
        $t->integer('imageable_id');
        $t->string('imageable_type');

        $t->softDeletes();
        $t->timestamps();

    });
}
```

And my classes,

Photo:

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {
    public function imageable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Room:

```
class Room extends Eloquent {       
    public function photos() {
        return $this->morphMany('Photo', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

I have seen an issue with reserved words ([like Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694319/laravel-4-save-a-polymorphic-relationships-record-undefined-method-newquery)) but that does not seem to be the issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run `$room->photos()->save($photo);` after you save the original.  The original doesn't exist yet, so there is no ID to associate.

Maybe it should throw an exception, maybe not.  Personally, I would rather it scream at me.

Comment: ...and there you have it. Thank you. I can see why they don't, but I would like them to throw an exception. If you are assigning the id a value of 0, there is obviously something wrong! Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, hope you are enjoying Laravel!

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

> $photo = $room->photos()->create(array('URL' => 'thePhotoURL.extension'));